# Using when with 2 AJAX calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two functions.. `addItem` and `removeItem` that `POST` to a given URL. These AJAX calls work fine. However, they need to be synchronous. I'm trying to make them synchronous by using `.when`. My code basically looks like this:

```
$.when(additem()).done(removeItem());
```

But this doesn't seem to be working correctly and the requests are getting fired at the same time.

I also tried to put one of the functions in the `complete` of the request, like so:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '/cart/update.js',
  data: {updates: updates},
  dataType: 'json', 
  complete: removeItem()
});
```

But that doesn't seem to be working either.. What is the right way to complete one AJAX request before starting the next?

Thanks

Comment: Using parentheses with `removeItem()` executes the function. To pass a callback function, don't use those parentheses.

Comment: You can use [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between referring to a function and invoking it.

- To refer to a function, use its name only.
- To invoke a function use its name followed by parenthesis.

When setting up callbacks (asynchronous or not), you want to refer to the function, not call it. Your inclusion of the parenthesis after your second function call makes the call happen immediately.

Try this:

```
$.when(additem()).done(removeItem);
```

Or:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '/cart/update.js',
  data: {updates: updates},
  dataType: 'json', 
  complete: removeItem
});
```

If you need to pass arguments to the callback, you must use parenthesis, but to avoid the invocation, the function should be wrapped in another function declaration, like this:

```
$.when(additem()).done(function(){
  removeItem(<arguments here>);
});
```

Or:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '/cart/update.js',
  data: {updates: updates},
  dataType: 'json', 
  complete: function(){
    removeItem(<arguments here>);
  }
});
```

Comment: Or just `complete: removeItem`

Comment: Thanks! But if I have to pass in an argument to `removeItem`.. I would do it like you had before the edit? I have to pass in the `id` of the item to remove..

Comment: @ToddT Yes, to pass arguments, you will need my prior syntax. I'll put it back as an option

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with how you're calling them. You're calling both of those functions immediately rather than passing them as arguments to `$.when` and `done`.

Since `$.ajax` returns a Promise (or Promise-like object) you can omit the `$.when` entirely.

```js
function addItem() {
  // $.ajax returns a Promise-like object
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log('Adding an item...');
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('Item has been added');
      resolve();
    }, 2000);
  });
}

function removeItem() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log('Removing an item...');
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('Item has been removed');
      resolve();
    }, 2000);
  });
}

// Promises implement a `then` function which runs when the promise resolves
addItem()
  .then(removeItem);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [jquery-ajaxQueue](https://github.com/gnarf/jquery-ajaxQueue)

or modify your code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '/cart/update.js',
  data: {updates: updates},
  dataType: 'json', 
  complete: removeItem
});
```

remember one thing is, if you saw a parentheses after a function, 
that means "execute", so if you set `removeItem()` for the callback `complete`, 
it won't be called as expect. it will be called when you set it to the `complete`.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers have addressed the fact that you were calling the function and passing the result instead of passing the function to be called. This answer is meant to highlight the new [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) features introduced in the ECMAScript 2017 language specification (ES8).

As you can see from the snippet below, each line waits for the previous line to finish before executing; whereas without async and await, each line would execute without waiting for the asynchronous calls to finish.

```js
const asyncFunc = text => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve(text), 1000)
})

async function main() {
  const hello = await asyncFunc("hello")
  console.log(hello)
  const world = await asyncFunc("world")
  console.log(world)
}

main()
```